# PyDev Eclipse Install on OSX Failing

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I'm having a similar problem to one of the earlier questions, but none of the recommendations has solved the problem. Trying to install PyDev in eclipse always fails to read the necessary files. I have the latest version of Eclipse (updated), I have tried multiple PyDev links including the nightly builds, and have tried installing Aptana. All will fail with the same sort of failed to read error. Would post a picture, but can't as a new user.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like my firewall was disrupting the installation to the point that it just timed out. There weren't any indications that this was happening, but the install works fine from an unsecured network (hotspot), but consistently fails behind a corporate firewall. I retested once I was behind the firewall again, and replicated the failure. I've seen this same time-out error in multiple questions that ultimately didn't get answered, so just wanted to include the resolution for my case.

Comment: Just to note, in this situation you could get the .zip files or the actual Aptana Studio 3 standalone. See: http://pydev.org/download.html for details on getting those.